# WEP authentication suddenly failing in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wep

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 and after a recent reboot, I'm now unable to authenticate to wireless networks using WEP encryption.

I can connect fine to open networks (no idea about WPA).

When trying to connect via WEP, I'm continually prompted for the network key, which I know I have entered correctly (and should have been/is saved in my keyring anyway).

Everything had been working fine until the reboot. No updates had been installed or configuration changes made.

[Hardware-wise, everything looks fine](http://pastebin.org/113777), and the fact that connecting to an open network works just fine leads me to think this is a software issue.

I just don't know where to begin fixing it.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to more than one network?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your WEP connection is 64-bit.   The Ubuntu GUI no longer supports 64-bit WEP connections for security reasons (it is VERY insecure).

Anyhow, you can try setting up via the command line interface (terminal):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid [networkname]
sudo iwconfig key [0123456789] open
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

Do not include the [ ] brackets, this is where you need to enter your info.   Your 64-bit key should be TEN hexdecimal characters.

Hope this helps.